# dotnet application, specify environment for using appsettings

Tags: .net-core

I am NOT using ASP.NET Core

In ASP.NET core you can set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to development, staging or Production or whatever.

Then in code you can load appropriate appsettings file via

> IHostingEnvironment env

See code below:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
```

How do you achieve this in a .net core application as this is an ASP.NET Core feature and IHostingEnvironment is not available?

Comment: dasMulli wrote a fantastic article here: https://dasmulli.blog/2018/01/21/use-appsettings-json-and-environment-overrides-in-classic-asp-net-apps/

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the environment variable directly yourself by doing:

```cs
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")
```

Comment: It can also be useful to add `?? "Production"` in order to emulate the default value.